# Is this proof of Heavenly joy?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible-translation, exegesis

I have posted questions before about why we believe Heaven is utterly joyous when it says little, that is, next to nothing, about joy in Heaven in the Bible.

Hebrews 12:2-3

2 fixing our eyes on Jesus, the pioneer and perfecter of faith. For the joy set before him he endured the cross, scorning its shame, and sat down at the right hand of the throne of God. 3 Consider him who endured such opposition from sinners, so that you will not grow weary and lose heart.

Does this proove that Heaven is joyous- and so joyous that God crusified His son to make it so- or is the joy set before him the joy of one who has 'made the plan work'- redeemed us and brought us closer to God?

Comment: It says little... it may be because we have no feelings in heaven i.e. mad, sad, afraid, embarrassed, joy, and AWE (new feeling reported by npr.org in 2013).

Comment: I have since discovered a few 'bits' of the Bible that make it clear that there is joy in Heaven. It then took me an entire day to discover a quote from Jesus saying that anything (no matter how dear) we lose on Earth will be repaid, a hundred times over, in Heaven.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for "proof" that some text is being interpreted correctly, because previous questions haven't convinced him of a specific doctrine.  This essentially makes is a ["convince me question"](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/how-should-we-address-convince-me-questions).

Answer (score 2):

**Jesus left the pleasures of Heaven to save us:** Jesus left Heaven to save us so that we may also enjoy the pleasures of Heaven with Him. Since no one can enter Heaven with their own efforts and all are sinners, Jesus gave up everything for us to give us everything that He has.

**To bring joy in Heaven:** Jesus endured the pain and suffering of the cross for the sake of bringing joy in Heaven because their is joy in Heaven whenever a soul is saved.

> Then Jesus told them this parable: “Suppose one of you has a hundred
>   sheep and loses one of them. Doesn’t he leave the ninety-nine in the
>   open country and go after the lost sheep until he finds it? And when
>   he finds it, he joyfully puts it on his shoulders and goes home. Then
>   he calls his friends and neighbors together and says, ‘Rejoice with
>   me; I have found my lost sheep.’ I tell you that in the same way
>   **there will be more rejoicing in heaven over one sinner who repents** than over ninety-nine righteous persons who do not need to repent.
>   (Luke 15:3-7, NIV)

[John Gill's comment on Hebrews 12:2](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/gill/hebrews/12.htm)

> .... for the sake of which Christ underwent so much
>   disgrace, and such sufferings; namely, for the sake of having a
>   spiritual seed, a numerous offspring with him in heaven, who are his
>   joy, and crown of rejoicing; for the sake of the salvation of all the
>   elect, on which his heart was set; and for the glorifying of the
>   divine perfections, which was no small delight and pleasure to him.

**Joy beyond our imagination:** They joy and pleasure in Heaven is indescribable. We can't imagine. Think of this description of the joy in Heaven.

> ‘He will wipe every tear from their eyes. There will be no more death’
>   or mourning or crying or pain, for the old order of things has passed
>   away.”  (Revelation 21:4, NIV)

1. **No death:** Death is the most painful thing in this world. I can't imagine a world without death. How joyous it would be to live forever in the presence of God.
2. **No sorrow:** I can't imagine a world where their is no sorrow but only happiness. We have sorrows in this world due to countless reasons. Poverty, failure, career, job, family, sickness, disease etc. All these reasons for sorrow will be no more in Heaven.
3. **No pain:** This is my favorite part of Heaven. In this world there is pain everywhere. Our body is able to feel pain and this is torturing us everyday. We try our best to reduce pains but we can't stop it. Heat, cold, sickness, hunger, tiredness, physical pain, all these will be no more.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, I understand that the negations would create a perfected version of the now...However, many Christians believe that Heaven's joy exceeds any to be had here- yet there seems to be little (arguably no) firm evidence of this in the Bible. We know there will be joy, but joy might be the same as it is now, only without the affliction of pains...